# Custom lookup using search in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, vba7, vba6

I am not sure, how to fix this function.

if Isnumber(search) is true, then get value from lookup_table

after 2nd round, it ends

[Image of excel data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXMFP.png)

```
Function Slookup(lookup_value As String, lookup_table As Range) As String

Dim i As Integer
On Error GoTo Err
Dim valuetxt As Boolean
Dim cc As Integer

cc = lookup_table.Rows.Count

For i = 1 To cc
    valuetxt = IsError(Application.WorksheetFunction.Search(lookup_table.Cells(i, 1), lookup_value))
    If Not valuetxt Then
        Slookup = lookup_table.Cells(i, 2)
        Exit Function
    End If
    


Slookup = ExcelError.ExcelErrorNA

Err:

Next i

End Function
```

Comment: Commrnt out the 'on error' then let us know which line is causing an error

Comment: You cannot trap a run-time error using `IsError()`   In VBA you can more easily use `Instr()` and not the `Search()` worksheet function...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tim Williams is correct in noting that `IsError()` cannot trap a run-time error (`1004`). So, your `IsError()` isn't doing much, except providing the necessary `False` for `If Not valuetxt Then` when there is *no* error.

The real problem lies with the fact that your error handler stays within the loop. `On Error GoTo Err` will not be triggered once you are already inside `Err:`. The code fails at the third example, because it is the *second* time you run into an error.

I.e. in your third example, you'll get an error at
`IsError(Application.WorksheetFunction.Search("A", "E G F"))` and are moved to `Err:`. However, you're not exiting the loop, so now you'll get another error at `IsError(Application.WorksheetFunction.Search("B", "E G F"))` and the thing breaks down. (So, your *second* example actually also encountered an error, but it never encountered another.)

You can fix this as follows:

```
Function SlookupAdj(lookup_value As String, lookup_table As Range) As String

Dim i As Integer
Dim valuetxt As Boolean
Dim cc As Integer

cc = lookup_table.Rows.Count

For i = 1 To cc

    On Error Resume Next
    valuetxt = IsError(Application.WorksheetFunction.Search(lookup_table.Cells(i, 1), lookup_value))
    If Err Then
        Err.Clear
    Else
        If Not valuetxt Then
            SlookupAdj = lookup_table.Cells(i, 2)
            Exit Function
        End If
    End If

SlookupAdj = ExcelError.ExcelErrorNA

Next i

End Function
```

In this modified code, we run into the same error, but simply skip it, deal with the fact that there is an error (`If Err Then`), clear it, and then make sure we never reach the evaluation of `If Not valuetxt Then`.

Again, Tim Williams is correct in noting that the thing you are trying to do, is more easily accomplished using `Instr()`. Like so:

```
Function InstrMethod(lookup_value As String, lookup_table As Range) As String

Dim i As Integer
Dim valuetxt As Boolean
Dim cc As Integer

cc = lookup_table.Rows.Count

For i = 1 To cc

    valuetxt = InStr(lookup_value, lookup_table.Cells(i, 1))
    If valuetxt Then
        InstrMethod = lookup_table.Cells(i, 2)
        Exit Function
    End If
    
Next i

End Function
```